# Reader and Writer Interface for PHP

Tags: php, interface, dependency-injection, software-design

I've created two very basic Interfaces named ReaderInterface and WriterInterface, but I have removed WriterInterface from this example since it is unnecessary to illustrate my conundrum.

**ReaderInterface.php**

```
interface ReaderInterface
{
    public function read();
}
```

I have a concrete class called Datatable:

**Datatable.php**

```
class Datatable
{
    protected $cols;
    protected $rows;

    protected $reader;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cols = array();
        $this->rows = array();

        $this->reader = null;
    }

    public function setReader(ReaderInterface $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    public function load()
    {
        //Contents to follow below.
    }
}
```

I instantiate a datatable instance as follows:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=test", "user", "pass"); //Let's pretend this is a good connection.

$datatable = new Datatable();
$datatable->setReader(new DatatableReader($db));
$datatable->load();
```

My question is about implementing DatatableReader so that it can read from the database I pass in, and write to `$this->cols` and `$this->rows` in my Datatable object.

I see two approaches right off.

**1. Dependency Injection**

```
class DatatableReader implements ReaderInterface
{
    protected $db;
    protected $datatable;

    public function __construct(Datatable &$datatable, PDO &$db)
    {
        $this->datatable = $datatable;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function read()
    {
        //Execute prepared statement which returns 5 records.
        //Get the columns, and place them into an array.

        foreach ($columns as $col) {
            $this->datatable->addColumn($col); //Add a column to the datatable.
        }
    }
}
```

Then, my `Datatable::load()` method would be implemented as:

```
public function load()
{
    if ($this->reader != null)
        $this->reader->read();
}
```

**2. Weakly typed return from read().**

```
class DatatableReader implements ReaderInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO &$db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function read()
    {
        //Execute prepared statement which returns 5 records.
        //Get the columns, and place them into an array.
        return $columns;
    }
}
```

I would then call my `load()` method as follows:

```
public function load()
{
    if ($this->reader != null) {
        $retval = $this->reader->read();

        //Do stuff with the array of information returned from the reader.
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Of these two options, which is the best design?
2. Is there a third option that I'm overlooking?

Comment: first thing you should do is rename `Datatable` to `DataTable` and `DatatableReader` to `DataTableReader`

Comment: @Omar Why is that? Datatable is a compound word, just like Interface. You wouldn't spell Interface as InterFace would you?

Comment: @crush I have no idea which is 'correct', but when you google `datatable` you will notice that *everyone* has it as `DataTable`.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. What about my actual questions =}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 2. With option 1 you produce a recursion: `DatatableReader` contains object `Datatable` and vice versa.

The other bad thing with option 1 is that you abuse the `read` method to write to another object.
And only the concrete implementation (`DatatableReader`) knows about that object.
All objects that implements an interface should react in the same way.

Comment: Your first point is why I hesitated to go with Option 1 at all. Your second point is relevant, but I could say the same thing about Option 2. Since the return type of read is weakly typed in PHP, it is going to be different everywhere it is implemented. Also, as can be seen above, if I return an array of the data that was read from the source, then I have to loop over that data twice: once to read it from the source, and again to apply it to my concrete class after receiving it from read().

Comment: You could return an iterator object. Than you only have to read it once. [class.iterator.php](http://php.net/manual/de/class.iterator.php)

Comment: I still have to iterate it while fetching rows from the DB, then I'd still be iterating when I iterate the iterator =] That's two full iterations over the data, unless I'm missing something

Comment: you could return an iterator from your database fetch method. Here is an example with pdo. [link](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=86011)

Comment: and in your `read` method you always return an iterator. Than you only have to iterate once over the iterator.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. It does force me to return an iterator. What if I want to return a DOMDocument instead though, or an XML string

Comment: You can implement your own iterators for every input. The problem is that XML can be recursive. So you need a `RecursiveIterator`. Check this example for a [RecursiveDOMIterator](https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator).

Comment: Also you need to guarantee that the data format is always the same. So you must somehow convert the data in the iterators `current` method.